# Нужна ли запятая перед тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед тире, чтобы закрыть придаточное предложение?

Система этого класса включает в себя подсистему поддержки принятия решений, которая предоставляет руководителю интегральные показатели — например, подсистему мониторинга простоев оборудования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Система этого класса включает в себя подсистемы поддержки принятия решений, которые предоставляют руководителю интегральные показатели, — например, подсистему мониторинга простоев оборудования.

Запятая нужна, она закрывает придаточное предложение. Может быть, здесь использовать мн.число - "подсистемы поддержки". (Если подсистема мониторинга - это одна из систем поддержки принятия решений).

Comment: Нсколько помнится, вводное слово, начинающее собой присоединительный оборот, выделяется запятой вместе с этим оборотом, поэтому в данном предложении запятая после слова "например" не нужна.

Comment: Если обособление делается с помощью тире, то вводное слово в начале обособленной конструкции отделяется запятой: "Для него деньги означали свободу ― например, возможность выступить на своём поэтическом вечере в Париже ".

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что в предложении, которое мы здесь обсуждаем, вообще нужно тире. Здесь обычная присоединительная конструкция, которая должна быть выделена только запятой, а придаточное предложение заканчивается не словом "показатели", а в конце всего предложения: "Система этого класса включает в себя подсистему поддержки принятия решений, которая предоставляет руководителю интегральные показатели, например подсистему мониторинга простоев оборудования".

Comment: Такое оформление возможно (здесь авторское решение), но оно  сложнее для понимания,  плохо читается зрительно и невнятно будет произноситься, если читать его  с правильной интонацией.  Думаю, что автор в данном случае не ошибся с выбором.